# Can I use a strict filter in angularjs to search in all pages?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I've got a problem while developing a pagination div and trying to search using strict data. What I want to do is to search across all the pages, not only the actual one. Sorry if my english is bad, hope you understand what I want to do, here's a Jsfiddle example to help you to understand what I mean.

```
<div ng-controller="pageCtrl">
    <label for="searchByName">Search by Name:</label>
    <input name="searchByName" type="text" ng-model="search.NOMBRE" placeholder="Nombre" />
    <label for="searchByLevel">Search by Level</label>
    <select name="searchByLevel" ng-model="search.ESCALON_CONFIANZA">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option ng-repeat="n in [1,2,3,4,5,6]" value="{{n}}">Nivel {{n}}</option>
    </select>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="data in filtered | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit | filter:search:strict">{{data.NOMBRE}}, {{data.ESCALON_CONFIANZA}}</li>
    </ul>
    <pagination data-boundary-links="true" data-num-pages="noOfPages" data-current-page="currentPage" max-size="maxSize" class="pagination-small" data-previous-text="&laquo;" data-next-text="&raquo;"></pagination>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/neox55/uL4khjo7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried reordering your filters so that your search happens **before** you restrict data for pagination purposes ?

```
<li ng-repeat="data in filtered | filter:search:strict | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit ">{{data.NOMBRE}}, {{data.ESCALON_CONFIANZA}}</li>
```

**EDIT** To answer your issue with the pagination : the $watch in your fiddle does not work properly and this is why your page number never gets recalculated. By default, $watch checks change based on reference inequality so you either need to $watch each of your individual changing variables (e.g. $scope.search.NOMBRE, not just $scope.search whose reference does not change) or use the optional parameter objectEquality to make a check based on angular.equals. This can have adverse effects on performance if your object is complex, but since your search item, I would recommend trying something like this :

```
$scope.$watch('search', function (term) {
    $scope.filtered = filterFilter($scope.list, term);
    $scope.size = $scope.filtered.length;
    $scope.noOfPages = Math.ceil($scope.filtered.length / $scope.entryLimit);
}, true);
```

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, I tried using filters in that order and it does works, thanks a lot! but now I have another problem, pagination doesn't fit the results after that.

Comment: Woooah! It really solved my issue, thanks again for the help Sycomor, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Thanks, this answer help me so much, but could you explain what is `filterFilter()`? I searched through the documentation and there is no `filterFilter()`